# How to put a partial scss file in the right position in main.css

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem namely in a partial scss file I have media-queries that correspond to a particular class. In the main.scss file I described the appropriate classes and for the mobile version it was necessary to use media-queries. Unfortunately, when I use a separate _media.scss file containing the appropriate breakpoints for the appropriate classes, after compiling to main.css, all media are above the appropriate class - and due to the cascade of code reading by css, all breakpoints are overwritten. Is it possible to indicate in scss where the file should be compiled?

I tried changing the position in the _index.scss file of the _media.scss file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The order of imports controls the order in which the css rules are placed in the output.

Comment: Instead of defining all your media queries in a separate _media.scss, you can define them right where you’re defining each class. This way, each class and its associated media queries will be closely linked.